# How to store csv file data into Database by building import/export utility/feature in Kentico Admin Tool?

Tags: kentico

I am learning Kentico and the requirement is to save csv file data into database by creating a import/export utility in Kentico Admin tool.

Kentico 10.0.44 version is used.

Can Kentico Import Tool be customized for this using handler or custom event hooks ?
Or is there any documentation to build a custom feature/utility in Admin Tool ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no support for using the Kentico Import Toolkit (KIT) via command line or any other option.  You need to use the UI to perform the import.

That being said, you can write some standard asp.net code to perform the import of the CSV into Kentico.  Keep in mind you want to use as much of the Kentico API as possible to ensure your data will be properly imported.  If you don't use the API, you could end up with orphaned data, issues with workflow, etc. and they will cause a huge problem later on.

*** **Update** ***
I stand corrected, you can use a pre-created profile and use the KIM with a given profile to import data via the CLI.  [Documentation is here](https://docs.xperience.io/k10/external-utilities/kentico-import-toolkit#KenticoImportToolkit-Importingdatafromthecommandline) for version 10.

Comment: Thanks Brendon , Yes , I am following this article :
https://docs.xperience.io/k11/custom-development/creating-custom-modules/manually-creating-the-interface-for-custom-modules